# Referring to some attribute of an inanimate object — use "who's"?

Tags: pronouns, adjectives, possessives, animacy

This came up in describing an input to a function:

> A handle to the daemon who's name is desired.

(Daemon is a type of process on a system.)

Somehow, "who's" just doesn't seem right because it's not a who, but a what. Could one say "... the daemon what's name is desired"?

Comment: Well, for starters, it would be "whose" anyway. "Who's" is short for "who is".

Comment: the daemon named desire...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is wrong, but not because a daemon is a thing rather than a person — "who's" doesn't indicate possession, it's a contraction of "who is". You need *whose*, which is a possessive pronoun and adjective, like *his*, *hers*, etc. So, just like you'd say "his name", you'd say "whose name", or "its name".