# What is it called when something is described by what it isn't?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I'm not looking for a particular part of speech.

A corollary to this idea, and in some ways the opposite, is when something is defined by/as itself. A lot of times you will find this in bad dictionaries when the definition of a word refers to a word whose definition refers to the original word. I am wondering if there is a word to describe this phenomenon.

I also recognize that using 'whose' above is grammatically incorrect, as it refers to a person. What would I replace it with?

Comment: I think those are actually two questions, none of which I understand properly. Could you please expand your questions, so that we get of better understanding of what you're looking for?

Comment: I totally agree with _FX. your statements seem to be a incomplete in the meaning they wish to convey. Please elaborate.

Comment: You mean for example "invisible" as contrasted to "transparent" or "unimportant" as contrasted to "trivial"?

Comment: By "described by what it isn't" do mean as in "This question is not clear"?

Comment: The first question seems perfectly fine to me: I take it to refer to words like "foreign" and  "inverterbrate", that mean "everything that isn't (something)".

Comment: negative definition was the term I was looking for in the title question, though I always prefer a single word over an expression.

Comment: The second idea was an afterthought that I should have explained better. It is somewhat like the opposite of the first. I'll edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: I think the second idea you're talking about is called using a [circular definition](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsACircularDefinition.htm)

Comment: @Peter Cameron: No-one else has addressed your second question, possibly because you're only supposed to ask a single question in a single post. It's probably been dealt with before, but let me assure you there is nothing wrong with *"...a word whose definition..."*. If there are any pedants who disagree, that's because they're, well, pedants.

Comment: [Use of *whose* when referring to some attribute of an inanimate object](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3477/referring-to-some-attribute-of-an-inanimate-object-use-whos)

Comment: Can you give an example? Would "non-believer" be one?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question! Are you looking for a word for “negative definition”?

In the theory of logic something can be defined with “double negation”.

In philosophy, Hegel helps with antithesis ‒ the opposite of thesis ‒ to explain ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is "negative definition".  It is often used where it is much easier to contrast something with what it isn't than define exactly what it is.
[This](http://academic.csuohio.edu/polen/LC9_Help/2/25negative.htm) gives an example (rather simplistic but...).

Answer (score 2):

Theologically, the term used for definition through negation is *apophatic*.

Definition:

> (Of knowledge of God) Obtained through negation. The opposite of cataphatic.

Example:

> Eastern Orthodox Christianity emphasizes *apophatic* theology - the Western equivalent is sometimes called ‘negative’ theology.

([Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/apophatic))

Comment: I don't know why this is being downvoted -- apophatic and cataphatic are actually the most technically correct terms, in philosophy or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In art, the terms "interstities," "negative space," and "figure-ground" are often used.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with **negative definition** is this can have quite a wide range of meanings, not just the one OP seems to be looking for.

I therefore suggest **antonymic definition** (as used in [the second line of the third paragraph here](http://www.ballardian.com/a-thousand-cerise-and-cyclamen-lights)), where I think even without the context, it's quite clear exactly what is meant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this sort of entry:

> *recursion* n. See *recursion*.

- even if indirect, i.e. via other entries.

This we would call a *circular definition*.
But something defined by its opposite? What could *that* mean?

And using *whose* in your sentence is perfectly okay to avoid a clumsy locution like "the definition of which".

Answer (score -2):

Even though I am not able to interpret your question perfectly, in case you mean the habit of using the wrong words at wrong places, then it is called **Malapropism**:

> The blundering use of an absurdly inappropriate word or expression in place of a similar sounding one.