# Usage of "whose" not referring to a person

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, possessives, animacy, possessive-of-which

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Referring to some attribute of an inanimate object — use “who's”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3477/referring-to-some-attribute-of-an-inanimate-object-use-whos)

I noticed the use of "whose" in the following sentence I wrote does not refer to a person:

> A recent post on Less Wrong, Levels of Action, reminded me of a game I created whose dynamics I wanted to explore.

I use "whose" in this way fairly often.  I'm just wondering, is it correct Standard English?  If not, what would be a more correct way of expressing the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in American English - according to Mr Webster himself!
[image]

[A philosophical and practical grammar of the English language By Noah Webster](http://books.google.com/books?id=iHoSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA32&dq=%22use%20of%20whose%20in%22%20grammar&cd=2#v=onepage&q&f=false)

I suppose in BE the 'correct' form might be: "the dynamics of which I wanted to explore" - but that sounds like you you are trying to be German.

Comment: Do you mind using the formatting for a link to hide URLs like that? ;)

Comment: @MrHen - linkifier was having some issues with the url - fixed it

Comment: +1 to this answer. The usual problem concerns using "that" for persons (i.e., "he is the criminal that stole the sofa"). But "whose" to indicate possession is unobjectionable.

Comment: Meh. That bashing of German is completely uncalled for *and* completely wrong. The whole *whose* issue is a very, very English phenomenon. No German in his right mind would ever replace "whose dynamics" with "the dynamics of which", whether in German or in English.

Comment: @Reg - Blame Conan Doyle: "Only a German is so uncourteous to his verbs"

Comment: Oh, make no mistake, I am very well aware how very awful [The Awful German Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Awful_German_Language) is in general! But this one thing just ain't true. I guess that's because *dessen* and *deren* aren't verbs.

Comment: It was more the point that in English you can use the 'wrong' word if it makes it more readable - there are rules but you can ignore them